How can I save a log of every attempt to insert a Lead without duplicate logs?
I have a requirement that every attempt to insert a Lead gets logged into a custom Lead_Log__c object. I cannot seem to get this to work while handling partial success inserts and also inserts of >200 records.
I started with the Lead before insert trigger. I need the log to be created even if the Lead fails validation, and after insert gets run after validation.
Since the log needs to be created even if the Lead fails validation, and the entire transaction gets rolled back in that case, I've tried creating a platform event for the creation of the log.
public without sharing class LeadTriggerHandler {
  public void beforeInsert() {
    List<Lead_Log_Event__e> logEvents = new List<Lead_Log_Event__e>();
    // create events
    EventBus.publish(logEvents);
  }
}

public without sharing class LeadLogEventTriggerHandler {
  public void afterInsert() {
    List<Lead_Log__c> logs = new List<Lead_Log__c>();
    // create logs
    Database.insert(logs);
  }
}

However, in the case of partial successes, the trigger can be run twice, kicking off the platform event twice and thus creating extra logs.
If I create a static variable tracking the first execution, that static variable will not be reset after the first 200 Leads.
public without sharing class LeadTriggerHandler {
  private static Boolean firstTry = true;

  public void beforeInsert() {
    List<Lead_Log_Event__e> logEvents = new List<Lead_Log_Event__e>();
    // create events
    if (firstTry) {
      EventBus.publish(logEvents);
    }
    firstTry = false;
  }
}

public without sharing class LeadLogEventTriggerHandler {
  public void afterInsert() {
    List<Lead_Log__c> logs = new List<Lead_Log__c>();
    // create logs
    Database.insert(logs);
  }
}

A common solution for this issue when dealing with update triggers is to make a static Set to track which records have already been processed. This doesn't work for me since I have to do this in before insert where the objects don't have Ids yet.
I have one idea of how to get around this, but my gut feeling is that there should be an easier way. I could serialize the object and create a checksum that I store on the Lead_Log__c so that I'd have something to compare against to avoid inserting duplicates. I would need to use CreatedDate in the checksum so that a second attempt to insert the lead would get logged, however I'm not sure if I can rely on CreatedDate to not tick up between trigger executions with partial success. Even if I can rely on CreatedDate, my gut feeling is there should be an easier way.
Does anyone know how to get platform events to publish only once during partial success inserts, but still work for inserts of >200 records, and include invalid records in the platform event?

There's more than one relatively unique identifier you can use. Allow me to introduce you to hashCode(). This creates a relatively unique signature that you can use to detect if two objects are likely the same object. You can use the Set<Id> concept by tweaking it slightly:
static Set<Integer> hashCodes = new Set<Integer>();
// ... some time later
Integer hashCode = record.hashCode();
if(hashCodes.add(hashCode)) {
  // This is the first time we've seen this record
}

The add method returns true if the Set is modified (i.e. it did not already contain that unique value). Note that audit fields aren't updated until the "after" save triggers when the record is reloaded from the database after the temporary save, so your hashCode values will match.
You could also generate an hMAC or other signature, but cryptographic functions are significantly more expensive in CPU time than hashCode calls, but they have a much lower chance of collision. Of course, if two records contain exactly the same values, a collision will happen anyways.
